# Flex 4 Panel skin has dependency on 'pattern_147.gif' -- Where is this?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, skinning, flexmojos

I am trying to create a new skin for the spark Panel based on a copy of the existing skin `spark.skins.spark.PanelSkin`.  Inside my skin is the following:

```
            <s:Rect id="tbFill" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="1">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:BitmapFill source="@Embed('assets/pattern_147.gif')" fillMode="repeat" />
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
```

But I am getting a flex compiler error that says it cannot find this.  Where can I locate it so I can add it to my project?  I don't know if it makes any difference, but I am using Maven/Flexmojos to get my Flex 4.1 SDK SWC files.  I am OK with working around the existence of this GIF, but it strikes me as odd that Adobe would create this dependency then not give you the asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title bar fill from sdk 4.1 (build 16076) which is a stable build produces the following code:

```
<s:Rect id="tbFill" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="1">
    <s:fill>
        <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
            <s:GradientEntry color="0xE2E2E2" />
            <s:GradientEntry color="0xD9D9D9" />
        </s:LinearGradient>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

You're probably using nightly builds of the sdk, which might explain such an oversight.

Comment: Thanks -- where can I go in the SDK to find the source of these skins?